# Is there a new Guest Additions for VirtualBox 4? If so, where is it?

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

Is there a new Guest Additions for Virtualbox 4? If so, where is it? I've looked all over but can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.  It's typically located in the VirtualBox installation directory and is an ISO file (VBoxGuestAdditions.iso).